# Call a javaScript url when a visitor clicks inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

How to execute a javaScript url when a visitor clicks inside div

**Like this example** :

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.youtube .play,.youtube img{cursor:pointer;position:absolute}
.youtube{position:relative;padding-bottom:56.23%;height:0;overflow:hidden;max-width:100%;background:#000;margin:5px}
.youtube embed,.youtube iframe,.youtube object{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:100;background:0 0}
.youtube img{bottom:0;display:block;left:0;margin:auto;max-width:100%;width:100%;right:0;top:0;border:none;height:auto;-webkit-transition:.4s all;-moz-transition:.4s all;transition:.4s all}
.youtube img:hover{-webkit-filter:brightness(75%)}
.youtube .play{height:72px;width:72px;left:50%;top:50%;margin-left:-36px;margin-top:-36px;background:url(//i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png) no-repeat}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="youtube" data-id="YQHsXMglC9A"></div>
    
</body>

<script>
/* Light YouTube Embeds by @labnol */
/* Web: http://labnol.org/?p=27941 */

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
        function() {
            var div, n,
                v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube");
            for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
                div = document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute("data-id", v[n].dataset.id);
                div.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
                div.onclick = labnolIframe;
                v[n].appendChild(div);
            }
        });

    function labnolThumb(id) {
        var thumb = '<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg">',
            play = '<div class="play"></div>';
        return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play;
    }

    function labnolIframe() {
        var iframe = document.createElement("script");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1");
        iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
    }

</script>

</html>
```

**Like this picture**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjuap.png)
.

**Html code + javascript** :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="a" style="background-color:#999; height:90px; width:250px;" >Click here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World!");
</script>
```

**Or** :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do I run javaScript url when a visitor clicks inside div ?

Comment: You probably meant run a javascript function, right? So that way, when someone clicks on the div, it does an action?

Comment: @PedroChiiip Yes , For page speed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to run a JavaScript function when your div gets clicked. You just need to add an `onclick()` event to your `<div>` tag and declare that function. So your div would be something like this:

```
<div id="a" style="background-color:#999; height:90px; width:250px;" onclick="writeFunction();">Click here</div>
```

And the function, with the same name as you declared on your onclick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function writeFunction(){

document.write("Hello World!");

}
</script>
```

As you have used document.write and i have kept that, it does not show the result that you have illustrated in your picture and your div is vanishing. In order to do as you have imagined, you have to add a `<p>` element which is initally blank:

```
<p id='text'></p>
```

and then ask your function to set its text, like this:

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

You can learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 1):

Something liked this would do it...

```js
function clickMe() {
 alert("You clicked me!")
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="a" style="background-color:#999; height:90px; width:250px;" onclick="clickMe()" >Click here</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of trying to run a script, you should try to run a function.
For example

```js
function test(){
  document.write("Hello World!")
}

function test2(){
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hello World!"
}
```

```html
<div onclick="test()">
  <p> Click me </p>
</div>
<div onclick="test2()">
  <p> Click me (won't remove screen) </p>
</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Clicking on the first div will call the test() function. This function will however overwrite everything on the screen, that's not what you want.

The second method doesn't do that, instead it sets the content of the third div to "Hello World!"